# R with 36 cores is much slower than R with 8 cores

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, benchmarking

[image]

On the right hand side is the result from EC2 instance with 36 cores and 64GB RAM while on the left is my laptop with 8 cores and 8GB RAM.

I'm new to running R on AWS EC2 instance, so probably I need to configure my R in order to make use of the EC2 instance raw compute power.

Could someone please advise on how or is there anything that I miss here?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you submit there is not parallelized. R uses only one core. You should inform yourself about parallelization in R (either you need to use packages that parallelize internally, or you need to write parallelized code yourself). But even if the code was parallelized, parallelization overhead would still slow this down since each task needs basically no time.

Comment: Your laptop max turbo might be higher than the AWS instance, and you probably have no competition for L3 cache or memory bandwidth.  Also, a quad-core laptop has *better* single-thread memory bandwidth and latency than a big Xeon, so cache misses are less costly.  (IDK if your benchmark does enough iterations to fully warm up and amortize startup slowness.)  You haven't given the specs on your laptop (e.g. i7-6???MQ at what GHz), but a big Xeon is generally not amazing for single-threaded throughput.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your insightful comments. Would you suggest some other AWS EC2 instances which are best optimized for R's single-thread memory behavior?

Comment: @PeterCordes the laptop is i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors. Would you know other EC2 instances which are great for R (for non parallel compute)?

Comment: @AfiqJohari: I assume Amazon runs most of its VM instances on similar hardware.  The underlying physical hardware is always going to be a big Xeon (not great per-thread bandwidth especially with Skylake, and not-great mem latency).  IDK if that's a problem for R or not.  If the working set first in L2 cache, you're fine.  But max turbo is still limited, either inherently or by other instances using power budget on the same physical socket.  The fastest single-threaded x86 CPUs are probably quad-core desktop with fast DRAM, like i7-6700k, in case that's relevant to you at all.

Comment: Since you have a laptop with a Coffee Lake CPU that runs R fast, why not just use that?

Comment: @PeterCordes good question. For some other R scripts that I have, I keep getting memory limit. Otherwise my intention with EC2 instance is to be able to run my R scripts faster.

Comment: Running benchmarks with measurements in the nanoseconds isn't a good comparison. Here's something that would take more than a few milliseconds```rnorm(1E7)```

Comment: @Cole probably a poor word choice to use the 'benchmark' function there. My intention is not to do benchmarking. I just want to show that running R script on a more power machine doesn't straightaway solve my computing needs if my R codes somehow couldn't take advantage of the extra cores and threads. Another example if I run this example here, my machine is still faster or similar https://www.remixinstitute.com/blog/why-machine-learning-is-more-practical-than-time-series-in-the-real-world/#.Xa_s0ugzZPa

Comment: @Roland I think you hit the right reasoning here. While I'm aware of some parallelization in R (parallelized library or write my own), suffice to say that my R usage is still pretty much limited to building some Proof-of-Concept data products. If I want to deploy into production, then I may need to worry and it's then justifiable to think of how to optimize the codes. At this stage, such re-writing for optimization is not going to add extra values to my current work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the better answer here.

Quite disappointing with the unnecessary downvotes.

https://github.com/csantill/RPerformanceWBLAS/blob/master/RPerformanceBLAS.md

> We frequently hear that R is slow, if your code makes heavy usage of
>   vector/matrix operations you will see significant performance
>   improvements.
>
> The precompiled R distribution that is downloaded from CRAN makes use
>   of the reference BLAS/LAPACK implementation for linear algebra
>   operations, These implementations are built to be stable and cross
>   platform compatible but are not optimized for performance. Most R
>   programmers use these default libraries and are unaware that highly
>   optimized libraries are available and switching to these can have a
>   significant perfomance improvement.

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if this answer had anything to do with the performance difference that you show above.  Taking logarithms has nothing to do with BLAS/LAPACK, which is for linear algebra ...

Comment: @BenBolker, the example is merely for reproducible reason. Since then I've learned about parallel package and also the BLAS/LAPACK. Both helps to answer my question.